# abstract syntax tree for imperative languages

Tags: parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, imperative-programming

I am looking for an abstract syntax tree representation that can be used for common imperative languages (Java, C, python, ruby, etc). I would like this to be as close to source as possible (as opposed to something like LLVM). I found [Rose](http://rosecompiler.org/) online but it is only able to handle C and Fortran. Does this exist?

Answer (score -1):

You won't find "one" universal AST that can represent many languages. People have been searching for 50 years.

The essential reason is that an AST node implicitly represents the precise language semantics of the operator it encodes, and different languages have different semantics for what are apparently the same operators.

For example, the "+" operator in modern Fortran will add integers, reals, complex values, and slices of arrays of such things.  Java "+" will add integers, reals, and glue strings together.   If I wrote "a+b" in "universal AST", how would you know which semantic effect the corresponding AST encoded?

What you can do is build a system in which the ASTs for different languages are represented uniformly, so that you can share tool infrastructure across many languages.   This is done by many [Program Transformation Systems (PTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation), where you  provide the grammar (or pick one from an available library), and the PTS parses and builds an AST using its uniform representation.  Most PTS provide additional support to analyze and transform the code.

So, all you need is a PTS and some sweat to define a grammar.  That's really not true; getting a grammar right for a real language is actually pretty hard.   Worse,  there's a lot to [Life After Parsing](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html) because you need the meaning of symbols and additional inferences such as control and data flow analysis. So you need full front ends (e.g., parsing, name/type resolution, flow analysis, ...), or as much as you can get, if you don't want to be distracted for months before beginning your real work.

What this means in practice is you want to find a tool that handles the languages of interest to you, with mature front ends already available:

- Rose (you already found this) handle C, C++ and Fortran.  It has no built-in parsing capability of its own; its front ends are custom built.  So it is apparantly hard to extend to other languages.  But it has good flow analysis capabilities and provides means to transform the code via hand-write AST walks/smashes.
- [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) handles C and C++.  Clang also uses hand-built front ends.  It can also transform code, again by hand-written AST walks/smashes, with a small amount of pattern matching support.  As I understand it, you have to use the LLVM part of Clang to do flow analysis.
- Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) has full front ends for C, C++, Java and COBOL, and full parsers for many more languages such as Python. DMS provides pattern-based analysis and source-to-source transformation. It operates directly from a grammar (see one for [Oberon, Nicklaus Wirth's latest language](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSParsers.html)). (I don't know of any tool that handles Ruby, which is famously hard to parse; I understand its grammar is ambiguous, and DMS is good at handling ambiguous grammars).